# Is it possible to use Netezza ODBC driver on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, odbc, netezza, unixodbc

The Netezza ODBC Drivers are officially supported on SUSE and RedHat. I'm trying to get the driver to work on Ubuntu 14.04.

I've been testing the connection via:

```
sudo isql -v NZSQL
```

Which initially returned:

```
[unixODBC]Error occurred while loading translation library
```

I tried to debug by running:

```
sudo strace isql -v NZSQL
```

This showed that isql was searching for a non-existent libc.mo file. I was able to resolve this by setting locale to en_AU and creating some symlinks to that libc.mo file.

Now isql fails with a communication timeout.

Currently

```
sudo strace isql -v NZSQL
```

Hangs for a couple of minutes on

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5480), sin_addr=inet_addr("SERVER-IP-HERE")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT|POLLERR|POLLHUP}])
```

And then fails with

```
sendto(3, "\0\0\0\10\0\1\0\3", 8, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
sendto(3, "X", 1, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

Is this a fool's errand? Has anyone had success using Netezza ODBC drivers on Ubuntu? Any suggestions on how I might resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. I am currently running the Netezza ODBC driver on Ubuntu 14.04.

You may need to create symlinks to the translation (e.g. English language) files, as I mentioned in the OP here:

```
I tried to debug by running:
sudo strace isql -v NZSQL
This showed that isql was searching for a non-existent libc.mo file. I was able to resolve this by setting locale to en_AU and creating some symlinks to that libc.mo file.
```

The timeout described above was due to an unrelated firewall issues -- the Netezza server was refusing connection from my IP, which had nothing to do with the driver.